# Display wrong price on list page when multi store

Tags: price, enterprise-1.14

I am using **Magento EE 1.14.3.0** with **multi store and has configurable products**.

Product is **the configured with price, special price** and for associated simple product given price with - number.

Problem is with **price `as low as` in category list page**. It displays correct on **product detail** page but **category list** page it displays wrong calculated value.

In first store it **displays correct values** on both **category list & product details page**, But for **second** store it **displays wrong value**.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue comes in when one product is assigned to more than one store & given discount in nagative number to associated simple product of configurable product.

when same product is assigned to multiple websites, then it calculates (subtract amt.) no of times product is assigned to sites,

The price variation will be applied as many times product is assigned to websites.,
e.g. : if we have product and assigned different two websites and set a price variation of 5, then the variation will be 10 instead 5. If we assigned product for three websites, then the variation will be 15.